# Fetching the frequency of a unique number within an array for a list of db queries in sqlalchemy/postgresql

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy

I am having a hard time figuring out a way to find a solution to the above question. Here are the details.

Let's say we have Table X which contains different products, and each product has a **unique integer id and a unique code**. We also have Table Y, which contains different variants of each product in Table X who have slight variations in a product name, length, width etc. Therefore there's a **one-many** relationship defined between **Table X** and **Table Y**.

The frontend displays all these product variants and allows them to be chosen from a list and export all of the chosen product details to a pdf. However, there's a weird way of choosing them, wherein if a **user clicks on a product, then all the product variants who have the same unique code are selected** ***if*** they are on the same list. That is, basically whenever a product variant is selected, the full product gets selected along with all its variants in the list. However, if the user wants, they can deselect each product variant **individually** as they please.

**Table Z** contains a log of all the product variant ids exported. Hence it looks something like this

id | exported_at | exported_by | product_variant_ids

1  | Some datetime   | Some user   | {1, 2, 3, 4} 
2  | Some datetime   | Some user   | {3, 4} 
3  | Some datetime   | Some user   | {6, 8, 9} 
4  | Some datetime   | Some user   | {1, 6, 7} 
5  | Some datetime   | Some user   | {3, 5, 7}

And so on..

Here you will observe that: 
 1. On each row, a product variant id can appear only once in the array
 2. However, a product variant id can appear at different rows

I want to calculate, for each **unique product variant id** present across all the rows, the sum of the frequency of them appearing across each row.

So for example, in the dummy table above, **product variant id 1** appears exactly twice in the whole table, in row 1 and row 4. Similarly, **product variant id 3**, in rows 1, 2, and 5.

I have tried to calculate it naively, something like

Naive algorithm in words:

> From a set of all unique ids present across the table,
>  for each
>   row check if each of the unique id in the set is present in each single
>   row 
>  and increase the counter each time it does.

I don't know how to write a subquery for it and hence, I was not able to tryout any queries on the postgres console.

It results in a very slow operation after only 15-20 logs when using an ORM like SQLAlchemy.

Can anyone guide me in the right direction what may be a more efficient solution?

Comment: I don't understand if you are asking about Postgres or Python.

Comment: Well I am asking about Python, but a postgres query will do too, so that I can convert it into a sqlalchemy orm query.

Comment: Great.  Then if it's a database question delete all the Python code, and if it's a Python question, then remove the DB references.

Comment: Updated the question.

Comment: `SELECT array_agg(id), pvid FROM (SELECT id, UNNEST(product_variant_ids) as pvid FROM Z) T GROUP by pvid` ? You get the list of id in the array and the size of the array gives you the count.

Comment: If you're asking for SQLAlchemy help, include your (relevant) models. And don't worry about mixing Python and SQL in an SQLAlchemy question.